# Assuring that Hibernate persistence worked on a junit test

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

If I have a test method marked as @Transactional, and I save an entity to the DB at any point in time, I should be able to fetch the new stuff (with changes) on the very next line of code, even though the transaction will be then rolled back (the default behavior of transactional unit tests), right?

In other words, if I have the following:

```
thisPhoto.likes.add(thisUser);
thisPhoto.save(); //the hibernate session will save this instance
...
thisUser = User.get(thisUser.id) // I even take the user instance again
newPhoto = thisUser.likedPhotos.get(0); //this should already contain the new photo, right?
assertEqual(newPhoto, thisPhoto);
```

Imagine that photo and user are both Hibernate based entities, where all the relations are properly set up and everything.

Nevertheless, when I reach the last line of code, I get an exception, that the likedPhotos collection has size of 0, and there is no element at index 0.

Why? How else am I supposed to test that the entity was persisted properly?

Answer (score 0):

`save` does not save immediately.  You have to `flush` the session to make sure the changes actually get persisted to the database.

Comment: actually, I do not even want it to reach the DB. I trust Hibernate for that. What I was actually expecting is that when probing for the (already updated) entity, the current session would have given me an updated one , even if the changes haven't been saved to the DB yet. I guess I am somewhat wrong, right?

Comment: actually, even manually flushing the session and then regetting the object doesn't return an updated one :(

Comment: are you using mysql?  Do you have the autocommit on?

Comment: no no I am using postgres, and until a couple of days everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be handling a list that belongs to `Photo` directly without calling `Photo.getLikes()`.  That's considered poor Object Oriented style under most circumstances.

Secondly, for most domain objects, it's pretty normal to not allow editing of its collections at all.  You should ask `Photo` to update it's list like so: `Photo.addLikedUser(User)`.  Then you can lock down your list for editing by returning `Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.likes)` in the `Photo.getLikes()` method.

Finally, in order to solve your issue, you probably need to call `User.addLikedPhoto(Photo)` in your `Photo.addLikedUser(User)` method.  I'm not certain that Hibernate will do this for you, especially prior to calling flush.